# How to compile Apache 2.4 with threading support on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu

Trying to install Apache 2.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 for a WSGI application, I want to do this properly.

So I read this in the Apache official 2.4 docs:

"The version of Apache and its runtime libraries must have be compiled with support for threading."

Now, a relatively easy way to install Apache on Ubuntu is by simply doing this:

`sudo apt install apache2`

My question is, will this make it so that the installed version of Apache and its runtime libraries must have be compiled with support for threading?

If not, can anyone tell me how to do this?

I have searched the Apache official docs on compiling and installing Apache, and it doesn't say anything about threading.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html

The following tutorial may help understand this a bit:
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/apache-mpms-explained/

I ran the following in Ubuntu:
`$ apache2ctl -V | grep -i 'version\|mpm'`

And the result may be useful in answering the question:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server MPM:     event
```

So, it seems that my Apache server is running the Event MPM, and the above tutorial says this about the Event MPM:

> Each process under Event also can contain multiple threads

So, I am wondering if this means that my version of Apache and its runtime libraries have been compiled with support for threading?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that installing Apache on Ubuntu 18.04 using apt:

`sudo apt install apache2` (and) `apache2-dev` (don't know if that's needed for threading support though)

Installs Apache with threading support by default.

**This is why I believe so:**

After doing a bit more research I stumbled upon a part of the mod_wsgi official documentation on checking your mod_wsgi installation.

It says you can check information on your Apache server by running the following command in your terminal:

`$ /usr/sbin/httpd -V`

Although for me, using Ubuntu 18.04, this works too:

`apache2ctl -V'

And the result tells me that my Apache version supports threading:

```
...
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
...
```